# Java Valicación de datos

Tags: java, condiciones, validación, else

Me asiganaron este enunciado y ese es el código que escribi. Por favor corrijanme y denme criticas. Gracias a todos.

Emitir listado con nombres y direcciones de personas que cumplan los requisitos, se deben ingresar los sgtes datos:

- Nombre del Postulante(Enter para fin)
- Dirección
- Código de sexo (H/M)
- Edad
- Años de Experiencia
- Estado civil (1= Soltero, 2 = Casado, 3=Viudo, 4=Divorciado)
- Dispuesto a vivir en otro lugar (S/N)

  ```
   import java.util.Scanner;
   public class  Postulacion {
       public static void main(String[] args) {
           Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);

           String nombre = "";

           while(! nombre.equals("Fin")){

               String direccion = "";
               char codigo = ' ';
               int edad = 0;
               int años = 0;
               int estado = 0;
               char dispuesto = ' ';

               System.out.println("Ingrese  nombre");

               nombre = teclado.nextLine();
               if (nombre.equals("Fin")) {

                   System.out.println("\n Fin de Programa");


                   }
                   else {
                       if (estado == 2) {

                       }

                       else {
                           if (edad == 35) {

                           }

                           else {
                               if (dispuesto == 'S') {

                               }
                           }

                           System.out.println("Nombre Postulante :" + nombre);
                           System.out.println("Direccion de Postulante" + direccion);
                           System.out.println("Pulse INTRO para continuar");
                       }
                   }   
           }       
           teclado.close();
       }

   }
  ```

Comment: Hola, bienvenidx a SOes. Por el contrario, cuéntanos tú cuál es el problema. ¿El código hace lo que te piden? Falla? Si no hay problema posiblemente cierren la pregunta.